# Need help with twig test template

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to create a test twig template in drupal 8, I followed "Create custom twig templates for custom module" from their website but it's not working for me for some reason. This is what I have:

Contents of folder test_twig_template:

test_twig_template.info.yml:

```
name: Test Twig Theme
type: module
description: Module to test if twig theme is working as intended
package: Custom
version: 1.0.0
core: 8.x
```

test_twig_template.module:

```
<?php
function test_twig_template_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_template' => [
      'variables' => ['test_var' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

test_twig_template.routing.yml:

```
test_twig_template.theme:
      path: /twig
      defaults:
        _controller: Drupal\test_twig_template\Controller\TestTwigTemplateController::content
        _title: 'Twig title'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

Code inside test_twig_template/src/Controller/TestTwigTemplateController.php:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\test_twig_template\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class TestTwigTemplateController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
    return array(
      '#title' => 'Test Twig title',
      '#theme' => 'my_template',
      '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
    );
  }
}
```

And finally inside test_twig_template/templates/my-template.html.twig I have:

```
  <p>Test twig template!</p>
  <p>test_var: {{ test_var }}</p>
```

Thing is if I remove this "'#title' => 'Test Twig title'," from my controller nothing gets displayed on my custom page. Otherwise it just displays this title "Test Twig title". 
Am I missing a call for twig somewhere or are my hooks_theme() not properly set up?

Comment: You’re simultaneously using `test_twig_template`, `test_twig` and `test_twig_theme` for the module’s machine name. You need to pick one and stick with it

Comment: I wasn't using 'test_twig' anywhere in my code, but I was mixing other two. Changed that, now it is 'test_twig_template' everywhere from module name to everything else. Still it's not working. Do you have any idea what else might be wrong?@Clive

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are messing around with your naming.

Since your module is called `test_twig_template` you must use that name for hooks and namespaces etc.

Fix these things and it should work.

> - Rename your `hook_theme()` from `test_twig_theme` to `test_twig_template_theme`.
> - Call your route `test_twig_template.theme`.
> - Your controller definition in your route must look like this, `_controller: \Drupal\test_twig_template\Controller\TestTwigThemeController::content`.
> - The namespace in your controller must be `namespace Drupal\test_twig_template\Controller;`.
> - Rename `test_twig_template/src/Controller/TestTwigController.php` to `test_twig_template/src/Controller/TestTwigThemeController.php` (the file name must match the class name).

That should be all, since your module is called `test_twig_template` it's important to use that name in all namespaces for your code to work properly :)

And then as @Hudri mentions your template shall only contain:

```
<p>Test twig template!</p>
<p>test_var: {{ test_var }}</p>
```

Head and body tags are provided by a general template in your theme.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100818/discussion-on-answer-by-jdrupal-need-help-with-twig-test-template).